# Would like to know if US patent 5,714,464 is still a valid Patent?

Tags: us5714464

Would like to know if the US Patent, 5,714,464 is still a valid Patent?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the patent owner did not pay the 12th-year maintenance fee that was due by 2/3/10 with a surcharge.  The USPTO's PAIR site indicates "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362."